# How to remove substring from PHP $var?

Tags: php, replace, preg-replace

When using PHP, how can I remove the characters between two forward slashes in a $var?

I tried:

```
$test = "gdgfdgdf/asg8&7_09()9/87iuyiuuyty";
$test = str_replace('/\s+/', '_', $test);
```

Note that `/asg8&7_09()9/` is dynamic data.

Unfortunately this doesn't give the intended results. How can I accomplish this using PHP?

Comment: str_replace does not work with regex, user preg_replace instead http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Comment: And even if it did work with regex, there is no space character in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question isn't exactly clear on if you want to remove just what is between the slashes, or the slashes as well.

```
$test = "gdgfdgdf/asg8&7_09()9/87iuyiuuyty";
$test = preg_replace( '/\/.*?\//', '_', $test );
print_r( $test );
```

Result

> gdgfdgdf_87iuyiuuyty

This code removes the slashes and their content. For the slashes to persist after processing, you could make the replacement `'/_/'`

```
$test = preg_replace( '/\/.*?\//', '/_/', $test );
```

Result

> gdgfdgdf/_/87iuyiuuyty

---

Within the match pattern

```
. Match any character (except newline)
* Match 0 or more times
```

[Regex Pal demonstration](http://www.regexpal.com/?fam=97346)

Answer (score 0):

Use preg_replace since it's dynamic data.

```
$test = "gdgfdgdf/asg8&7_09()9/87iuyiuuyty";
$test = preg_replace("/\/(.*?)\//",'_',$test);
```

Will return "gdgfdgdf_87iuyiuuyty"